# PythonMagick ColorSpace type

Tags: python, imagemagick, pythonmagick

I tried:

```
from PythonMagick import Image
img = Image("input.jpg")
img.quantizeColorSpace("sRGB")
```

And get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File...
>       img.quantizeColorSpace("sRGB") Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
>       Image.quantizeColorSpace(Image, str) did not match C++ signature:
>       quantizeColorSpace(Magick::Image {lvalue})
>       quantizeColorSpace(Magick::Image {lvalue}, MagickCore::ColorspaceType)

I understand that I must use type MagickCore::ColorspaceType. But how can I import that type into Python?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, this is a bug:
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=25229

The ColorspaceType is missing in some(?) versions of PythonMagick, ought to be fixed in more recent libraries (>=0.9.9).